# MySQL join query - lost connection

Tags: mysql, join, error-handling

I have a MySQL query that joins 4 tables in the same time and insert the results into 5th table at the same time.

2 tables have 50K records.
2 tables have 600K records.

```
Insert into `ICT`.`whs_field`
(`a_id`,
`table_id`,
`s_id`,
`f_name`,
`d_type`,
`d_size`,
`d_precision`,
`nul`,
`d_value`,
`ind`,
`o_id`)
select 
    Iwa.`a_id`, ivt.`a_id`, whfd.`s_id`, 
    whfd.`f_name`, whfd.`d_type`, whfd.`d_size`, 
    whfd.`d_precision`, whfd.`is_nullable`,
    whfd.`d_value`, whfd.`is_indexed`, whfd.`field_id`
from 
    ICT.whs_asset Iwa 
        inner join wh.dfd whfd 
            on whfd.`field_id` = Iwa.o_id
inner join 
    wh.dd wh 
        on whfd.dt_id = wh.`id`
inner join 
    ICT.`w_table` ivt 
        on ivt.`o_id`=wh.`id`
```

During join - it just stops and show error - 'lost connection to MySql'.

How to achieve above?
Should I join first 2 tables and then join third one and then 4th one and then do insert (incremental runs)?

Thanks.

Comment: Update your question with tables structures and your current SQL

Comment: Also post a `EXPLAIN [query]` because this question is related to query performance..

Comment: Are you trying this from an Apache/PHP server?

Comment: I tried from MySQL Workbench. Tried several times and still was the same issue..